# Как сформировать регулярное выражение в nginx?

Tags: nginx

Есть регулярка:

```
/\/tickets\/(.*)\/(.*)\//i
```

Которую я использую для распознавания строк вроде этой `/tickets/moscow/saint-petersburg/`, но проблема в том, что регулярка может захватить и строку `/tickets/moscow/tokyo/simferopol/` и так далее. Эту проблему я решил с помощью другой регулярки:

```
path.match(/\//g).length == 4
```

Какую регулярку в nginx мне нужно использовать и как её правильно записать, чтобы в nginx отлавливать только правильные строки с 4 слэшами? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Явно обозначьте, что ничего не должно быть после последней косой черты:

   ```
   /\/tickets\/(.*)\/(.*)\/$/i
   ```
2. Явно обозначьте диапазон допустимых символов, чтобы не ломать себе голову с жадным/ленивым сканированием. В придачу, стоит заменить квантификаторы, чтобы не допускать двух следующих друг за другом косых черт:

   ```
   /\/tickets\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\/$/i
   ```

Этого достаточно для решения проблемы. Вот результаты тестирования этого выражения на двух ваших примерах: https://regex101.com/r/nq6b2Z/1/tests.