# Выполнить файл в корне к которому обратились из вложенной папки

Tags: nginx

Идея такова, что у меня есть множество страниц двухмерной вложенности. То есть, папки вроде `/tickets/moscow/simferopol/`. Сейчас я просто нагенерил кучу этих папок и положил в них файл index.php, в котором написал

```
<?php include('/tickets/generator.php'); ?>
```

Изначально мне это самому не очень нравилось и у меня давно крутилась идея переложить это на nginx, чем я и попытался занятся. Задал [вопрос на StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799326/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-nginx/799348#799348), где получил ответ с нужной мне регуляркой для распознавания URL. Далее, я пытался применить регулярное выражение в `/location/`, чтобы все такие страницы использовали один единственный файл-шаблон из корня:

```
location ~ \/tickets\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/$ {
    root /var/www/developer/flaut/tickets;
    index generator.php;
}
```

Но nginx упорно кидает в меня ошибкой 404, мол, директория не найдена. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то эта конструкция не работала:

```
root /var/www/developer/flaut/tickets;
index generator.php;
```

А эта заработала как надо:

```
index /tickets/generator.php;
```

Разницы ведь никакой по сути нет. Работает и ладно.

Comment: Возможно, `root` задаёт путь относительно корневой директории домена, а не файловой системы.